# Create self join query

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I m trying to making attendance  system. For check in and check out table is designed as below

```
id
loginout (datetime) 
log_type[enum('I','O')]
fk_created_id
```

e.g records

Here now I want to two separate field check in and check out so that I can calculate the time diff or total hour of the day.

```
7   2014/07-31 06:00:32  I 1
8   2014/07-31 09:10:32  O 1
9   2014/07-31 09:30:32  I 1
10 2014/07-31 12:00:32   O 1
```

I m trying to create self join query but here I dont knw which two field will be compare ..
How to make self join query for this ?and in this type of query how to know which field will be compare ??

Comment: How can you be sure that the data is correct? And what will happen if you have 2 ins w/o out?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if [this](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/sql-joining-a-table-to-itself) can help you

Consider that tried-and-tested example: employees and managers. Here's the staff table from the database

```
mysql> select * from staff;
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | manager_id |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | Hattie     | Hopkins   |          4 |
|  2 | Henry      | Hopkins   |          4 |
|  3 | Harry      | Hopkins   |          5 |
|  4 | Helen      | Hopkins   |       NULL |
|  5 | Heidi      | Hopkins   |          4 |
|  6 | Hazel      | Hopkins   |          1 |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In order to see who reports to whom, we need to query the table to get the employees, and again to get the managers' names.

```
mysql> select e.first_name as employee, m.first_name as reports_to
    -> from staff e
    -> inner join staff m on e.manager_id = m.id;
+----------+------------+
| employee | reports_to |
+----------+------------+
| Hattie   | Helen      |
| Henry    | Helen      |
| Harry    | Heidi      |
| Heidi    | Helen      |
| Hazel    | Hattie     |
+----------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: The OP just wants to separate values that are currently stored in the same datetime column. I believe you completely misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

If everything in the data is correct, e.g. if outs=ins then the query is quite simple

```
select s1.*,s1.o-s2.i from 
  (select sum(loginout) o from t1 where log_type="O" and date(loginout)='2014-07-31') s1,
  (select sum(loginout) i from t1 where log_type="I" and date(loginout)='2014-07-31') s2
```